# How to plot one variable as a barchart with ggplot 2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a barchart comparing the values/observations within one variable. I'd then like to label the individual bars according to their names, stored as another variable within the dataset. I've tried geom_bar but I can't seem to get it to work.

Here is the head of my data

```
head(Patient11GeneExpressionProfile)

    Gene  ddCt value Fold Change
1   AIM2 -1.71470924   3.2823049
2   BCL2  1.13099363   0.4566011
3 BCL2L1 -0.40271320   1.3219918
4  BIRC2  0.07520729   0.9492057
5  BIRC3  1.46106210   0.3632256
6 CARD18          NA          NA
```

I've tried this but it is not working

```
ggplot(Patient5GeneExpressionProfile, aes( x = 'Fold Change')) + geom_bar()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome! We can’t help unless we see what you’ve tried thus far. Post your R code and we can go from there.

Comment: The use of `geom_bar()` will give you a count, where the height of the bars is proportional to the cases within the group. Could you explain in more detail what you want to see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the height of the bars (by `Gene`) to match the values in `Fold_Change`. If this is what you want, it will require `x` and `y` aesthetics. Add `geom_col()` as a layer and it will label your columns for free. Please note, `geom_col()` uses `stat_identity()`, which leaves the data as is. If you're partial to `geom_bar()`, then add `geom_bar(stat = "identity")` as a layer. Both should give you identical results. Try them out:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

data <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Gene, ~ddCt_value, ~Fold_Change,
  "AIM2", -1.71470924, 3.2823049,
  "BCL2",  1.13099363, 0.4566011,
  "BCL2L1", -0.40271320, 1.3219918,
  "BIRC2", 0.07520729, 0.9492057,
  "BIRC3", 1.46106210, 0.3632256,
  "CARD18", NA, NA    
)

# Option 1

ggplot(data, aes(x = Gene, y = Fold_Change)) +
  geom_col()

# Option 2

ggplot(data, aes(x = Gene, y = Fold_Change)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Answer (score 2):

Using your example:

```
Patient11GeneExpressionProfile = structure(list(Gene = structure(1:6, .Label = c("AIM2", "BCL2", 
"BCL2L1", "BIRC2", "BIRC3", "CARD18"), class = "factor"), `ddCt value` = c(-1.71470924, 
1.13099363, -0.4027132, 0.07520729, 1.4610621, NA), `Fold Change` = c(3.2823049, 
0.4566011, 1.3219918, 0.9492057, 0.3632256, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

I am guessing by "comparing the values/observations within one variable" you mean comparing the `Fold Change` for each gene. You need to pivot the data long first, and if you don't have two many genes:

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

pivot_longer(Patient11GeneExpressionProfile,-Gene)
# A tibble: 12 x 3
   Gene   name          value
   <fct>  <chr>         <dbl>
 1 AIM2   ddCt value  -1.71  
 2 AIM2   Fold Change  3.28  
 3 BCL2   ddCt value   1.13  
 4 BCL2   Fold Change  0.457 
 5 BCL2L1 ddCt value  -0.403 
 6 BCL2L1 Fold Change  1.32  
 7 BIRC2  ddCt value   0.0752
 8 BIRC2  Fold Change  0.949
```

We directly pass this into ggplot:

```
ggplot(pivot_longer(Patient11GeneExpressionProfile,-Gene),
aes(x=Gene,y=value,fill=name)) + 
geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge")
```

[image]

Comment: I would want this, but with just the Fold Change for each gene, no need to have the ddCt values on the graph. Would you please show me the code to do this. I'm sure it's super basic, but I'm a complete novice at this. Thank you!

Comment: then the code in the other answer should work. Did you try that?